# How to do the following entry gathering?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I want `out[b,i,j,c]:=params[indices[b,i,j,c],b,i,j,c]`. I am aware of [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) and [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) but not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# 5D or more tensor
params = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
# 4D tensor
indices = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [5, 4, 3, 2])
# We assume the number of dimensions of indices is statically known
# Otherwise you would need to use tf.while_loop
ndims = indices.shape.ndims
# Get shape of indices
s = tf.shape(indices, out_type=indices.dtype)
# Make grid of additional indices
ranges = [tf.range(s[i]) for i in range(ndims)]
grid = tf.meshgrid(*ranges, indexing='ij')
# Put grid together with indices
indices_all = tf.stack([indices] + grid, axis=-1)
# Gather result
out = tf.gather_nd(params, indices_all)
print(out)
# Tensor("GatherNd:0", shape=(5, 4, 3, 2), dtype=float32)
```